# searching custom field

Tags: custom-fields, search, search-results, custom-search, search-builder

I have a custom field for storing educational data. A person's degree is stored as either Btech or B.Tech or B.Tech.  so what should I give in search option so that I can get all 3 in my result in a single search?

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic pattern valid in `LIKE` operator of sql where clause.

For Eg - Using `%tech%` would result in all three rows.

Similarly you can use `[`, `]`, and `_` symbols.

To find more about search strings - see [Pattern Matching in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)  (AFAIK you can use only `LIKE` patterns here not `REGEXP`).

Comment: did you mean B%tech% in order not to get eg MATech as a result?

Comment: yes, that would work, `B%tech%` will list any value starting with `B followed by some chars and then tech <some chars>` which will exclude MATech from the result